# What should I do about a validateDOMNesting(...) error?

Tags: html, dom, tags, paragraph

[image]

I am getting this error in the console.  What should I do to solve this error?

Comment: Use quote or at least text to display your error message

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what might be going wrong, but the problem is that you have an `<h5>` header in the middle of a `<p>` paragraph.